# SQL Fixed Date from Previous Months

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I am looking to run a report each month to extract data driven by the date a specific task was opened.

The key field is 'progdate' (which will contain a date 'dd/mm/yyyy').

The extract is likely to be run in the last week of the month, which for the purpose of this example I'll say is the 25th (if that is a weekend or a bank holiday it will be run on the next working day).

When the code is run, it needs to bring back all 'progdate' returns from the 25th of the month two months ago and the 24th of last month.  (those two dates will be fixed and won't change from one month to the next so will always cover the exact same period).

ie.  If I am running this on the 25th October, it would return data from the 25th August, to the 24th September.    If I run it on the 25th November, it returns data from the 25th September to the 24th October .. and so on.

I have tried;

```
SELECT progdate, progtaskcode, progowner FROM progpoints
WHERE progdate BETWEEN to_char(add_months(sysdate, -2) 
AND to_char(add_months(sysdate, -1)-1)
```

Now this sort of works .. but will fall down if the code isn't run on the same day each month. If it's a holiday or weekend, it could miss out a day or two of data (or result in duplicates from one extraction to another).

Any idea on how to get this done without using Sysdate and coding in specifically the 25th of the month two months ago to the 24th of last month?

Many thanks!  :)

Comment: Your problem description is self contradictory. If 25 October falls on a Saturday (as it certainly does in certain years), you may need to run the report from 27 August to 26 September. Then 25 November is a weekday, so the report must be from 25 September to 24 October. So you have an overlap for 25-26 September. If you must avoid this overlap, then you **must** modify the "definition" of the report period. **How** you modify it is a business decision, it is not a programming question!

Comment: Thanks mathguy for the reply. Not sure I fully understand though.  If the report is coded to extract from two specific days (regardless of whether they are bank holidays or weekends or not), then no matter what day the report is run, then it will always just look for those dates?     (so i could run it on the 3rd, 10th, 30th and it would still only pull back from the two dates specified, i.e. the 25th (two months ago) to the 24th (of last month)?  If either the 24th or 25th are weekends or holidays, it just wouldn't return any data for those days (as nothing would show with those two dates)

Comment: I agree to mathguy, your requirements are not clear. Please clearly describe what do you expect if a) `SYSDATE` falls on weekend, b) `add_months(sysdate, -2) ` falls on weekend, 3) `add_months(sysdate, -1)-1)` falls on weekend. Also you should not compare **DATE** `progdate` with **STRING** `to_char(add_months(...`

Comment: Thanks Wenfried .. To answer your query;
a) sysdate will not fall on a weekend as the report will not be run on those days - if the due date of the 25th is, then it will just be run on the next working day which then makes the sysdate a weekday
b & c) both the same, if either of those days are weekends then it will not return data for those dates as they won't be held in the database. 

Is there not an easy way to just code to return data 25th day of two months ago from today to the 24th of last month ?

Comment: Still your requirements are not clear for me. Don't tell what you do not see, tell us what you expect as result. Give examples for `SYSDATE` and expecting lower-bound (`add_months(sysdate, -2)`) and upper-bound (`add_months(sysdate, -1)-1)`), esp. for last day of months - particularly 28th/29th of February.

Comment: OK, the results I expect to see would be the same as if I was running the report and the code specified the exact range with a date  (i.e., 
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE DATE BETWEEN '25-Sep-2017' TO '24-Oct-2017' 
I just don't want to type the actual date range so it can be run month after month without changing it. But thats what I want the code to do.   If there weekends, or only 28/29/30 days in the month it doesn't matter .. there won't be data to return, so I just want to see data when it's there between the range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

```
BETWEEN  TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE ,- 2), 'MONTH') + 24  
AND TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE ,- 1), 'MONTH') + 23
```

> Any idea on how to get this done without using Sysdate

It is possible if you have a Column in your table / schema containing information of calendar date or business date for which you run the query.

Comment: Thanks Kaushik. I guess my query around not using Sysdate may be solved with your code above (I'll try that in a little while), as this goes back to the first of the month two months ago and adds 24 (which gets me the 25th) and then to the 1st of last month, adding 23 (getting me to the 24th), that then gives me my range - using today as the sysdate starting point. So looking at that, no matter what day the report is run, it will always go to the 25th - 24th of the month range needed.

Comment: Thanks Kaushik. I have just tried this on a range of test dates (as I don't currently have access to the live environment as I am not at work) - and it provides me with the exact range of dates that I am looking for in the data extraction.